# python importing datetime module question

Tags: python, datetime, import

I have noticed while reading up on python datetime module there are times when responses will show

```
from datetime import datetime (or date or time)
```

and I'm not sure why I should or would do this. What is the rational behind this or could someone point me to some resources that might explain this?

Comment: As opposed to what?  I usually do `import datetime`, but if you're only going to use one class from there, it saves typing.

Comment: the datetime module has 3 inner modules that are typically imported. you can import them by saying ```from datetime import date``` or ```from datetime import datetime```. this is the same as ```import datetime.datetime``` or ```import datetime.date``` or ```import datetime.time```. the three inner modules of datetime are what are being shown as 'optional' imports. there isn't an actual syntax for importing where you can say import this OR import that

Answer (score 3):

The `datetime` module defines a bunch of different classes. If you just use

```
import datetime
```

Then you have to write things like `datetime.datetime.strptime()` -- the first `datetime` is the module name, the second is the class name. By using the `from` syntax you can shorten this to just `datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for the clarity on the subject

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime` module has multiple classes inside of it. Though at first the name may seem confusing, when you compare it to another module, like random, it starts to make more sense.

If we are only going to use `randint` from the `random` module, we don't want to import the whole random module so we will do something like this:
`from random import randint`

It's the same concept with datetime except the only part of datetime that we want is the `datetime` class. Inside of the module `datetime` there is a `datetime` class, just how in the module `random` there is a `randint` function.

If you wanted to import the whole random module then use randint you would do:

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(0, 5)
```

Just as if you wanted to import the whole datetime module, then use the datetime class you'd do:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Great explanation. After looking at the module documentation some more and doing some testing, I see now. Yes the datetime module and datetime type is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The first `datetime` refers to the module, whereas the second is a type defined therein. Depending on the application you can choose to import datetime.datetime, datetime.date or datetime.time.

More information can be found at the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for the clarity on the subject. Yes I have been reading the python documentation on the datetime module, but you and Barmar have brought clarity on what the documentation is saying

Answer (score 0):

---

## Datetime

---

#### Module Reference

[datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime)

---

*Disambiguation*:
**datetime**, is a builtin Python library (package, module), of the division of [Data Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html). It is basically a file that is named that way:

```
datetime.py
```

There are *classes* in that file, usually called module/class attributes.

---

**File  structure**

```
├── datetime.py
        ├── class date(builtins.object)
        ├── class time(builtins.object)
        └── class datetime(date)
```